Chemical equation numbering inside and outside of tables
I am trying to make a table where I have a chemical reaction, additional information and I want to number that chemical reaction. This numbering cannot be the same as in the mathematical equations. I also want to produce chemical reactions outside the table and continue with the same numbering. Something like in the image.

This is the farthest I have gone.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}        
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
    Text..... \autoref{tab:table1}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
        \hline
        Reaction& \(\Delta H_r^o\) & Reaction No. \\
        \hline
        \ce{A + B <--> C}& 10 & (R1)\\
        \ce{A + B <--> C}& 10 & (R2)\\
        \ce{A + B <--> C}& 10 & (R3)\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
\autoref{eq:Energy}
\begin{equation}
    E=mc
    \label{eq:Energy}       
\end{equation}
\ce{A + B <--> C}   (R4()
\end{document}

How can I make a counter that can work either in tables and outside the tables?

Welcome. // As an aside, it's a good idea to remove all packages before your post code, which aren't needed to compile your code and understand your problem. Thank you

You can use this:
\newcounter{reaction}
\newcommand\RNR{\refstepcounter{reaction}(R\thereaction)}

and then replace all the (Rxx) with \RNR.
